# how to see limit rotation range visual arc

Tags: bones, constraints

With the IK restraint you can limit rotation and see the range displayed as shown in the attached picture as the red semi circles. How can you visualize those ranges with the "limit rotation" constraint? I have other "stretch to" constrained bones that i need to limit the rotation of, but it's hard to do properly without the visual.

[image]

Comment: I don't think you can

Comment: I would suggest asking on [rightclickselect](https://rightclickselect.com) to see if you can find someone interested in implementing it.